# React component with debounceTime errors when using Sinon

Tags: reactjs, sinon, enzyme, jestjs

I have the following React component

```
class IncrementalSearch extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.onSearch$ = new Subject();
        this.onChange = this.onChange.bind(this);
    }
   
    componentDidMount() {
        console.log(this.simpleText);
        this.subscription = this.onSearch$
            .debounceTime(300)
            .subscribe(debounced => {
                this.props.onPerformIncrementalSearch(debounced);
            });
    }
     
    componentWillUnmount() {
        if (this.subscription) {
            this.subscription.unsubscribe();
        }
    }
       
    onChange(e) {
        const newText = e.target.value;
        this.onSearch$.next(newText);
    }
        
    render() {
        return (
            <div className={styles.srchBoxContaner}>
                <input
                    className={styles.incSrchTextBox}
                    type="text" name="search" placeholder="Search.."
                    onChange={this.onChange}
                />
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

I am trying to test this using Enzyme, Jest, and Sinon.  My unit test looks like the following

```
it('calls componen`enter code here`tDidMount', () => {
       
        const componentDidMountSpy = sinon.spy(IncrementalSearch.prototype, 'componentDidMount');
        const wrapper = mount(<IncrementalSearch />);
        expect(IncrementalSearch.prototype.componentDidMount.calledOnce).toEqual(true);
        componentDidMountSpy.restore();
    });
```

When I run the code I get the following error

> TypeError: this.onSearch$.debounceTime is not a function
>
> at IncrementalSearch.componentDidMount
> (src/components/common/incrementalSearch/IncrementalSearch.jsx:37:13)
> at Function.invoke (node_modules/sinon/lib/sinon/spy.js:194:51)

However if I comment out the debounceTime and leave everything else it passes.  How do I fix this?

Comment: Is there a specific reason for using Sinon to spy on method being called?
Jest has a spyOn method of its own:

const spy = jest.spyOn(IncrementalSearch.prototype, 'componentDidMount');
const wrapper = mount(< IncrementalSearch />);
expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalled(); // Or one of the methods...

To fix the actual issue you might need to import or mock rxJs

Answer (score 0):

I just added the following import and it worked

```
import 'rxjs/add/operator/debounceTime';
```

I still do not know why this does not work in unit tests and works when I am running the main app, but it works.

Comment: That import has side effects, meaning you don't rely on its returned value, but for the effects it has on the runtime. That means if your code works in your app, then that means that somewhere in your app, that import is being run. When you run a single component in isolation, then you are not running the entire app, so you don't run the code doing the import.

In general, this just smells of a poor practice of not declaring your dependencies. If your unit depends on `debounceTime` to exist as a utility function, then it should also import it in the module.